# After changing language to English, links to home directories don't work

Tags: 16.04, home-directory

new Ubuntu user here. I installed Ubuntu in Polish, but after noticing, that most of guides are in English (especially the one that are not in terminal), I decided to change language to English. Everything went well, except when pressing Files, I have "shortcuts" on the right task bar in Polish, and also they are linked to folders named in Polish. In /home I have /Desktop, but link is to /home/Pulpit (as shown on picture). Where/how I can change links to this folders?

[image: Print screen of the error after pressing Desktop folder]

This is what I got in `~/.config/user-dirs.dirs`:

```
XDG_DESKTOP_DIR="$HOME/Desktop"
XDG_DOWNLOAD_DIR="$HOME/Downloads"
XDG_TEMPLATES_DIR="$HOME/Templates"
XDG_PUBLICSHARE_DIR="$HOME/Public"
XDG_DOCUMENTS_DIR="$HOME/Documents"
XDG_MUSIC_DIR="$HOME/Music"
XDG_PICTURES_DIR="$HOME/Pictures"
XDG_VIDEOS_DIR="$HOME/Videos"
```

It should work, as it's directing to folders in English (as I have now).

Comment: Take a look at ~/.config/user-dirs.dirs (the mapping was maybe changed, after you changed the language)

Comment: Can you change yourself the linked folder shortcut (right-click on shortcut and then properties, or remove the shortcut and add a new shortcut?)?

Comment: When I use RMB on this items, I can open them in three different ways, sometimes rename (nothing happens), and open properties, where I can't do nothing.